# How to mock your own class that is not bound in the laravel container?

Tags: laravel

I have a simple action class looking something like this:

```php
class Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $client = app(ApiClient::class);
        return $client->ambassadors();
     }
}
```

The class `ApiClient` is not bound to the container and neither is the `Action` class. They are just regular classes that I use.

Now in my test I want to mock the `ApiClient` so that it doesn't make live calls to the API. I have tried to do this using:

```
public function test_that_it_returns_two_ambassadors(): void
{
    $action = app(Action::class);
    this->mock(ApiClient::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('ambassadors')->once()
                ->andReturn([
                    ['id' => 1337, 'company' => 'Test store 1', 'email' => 'marcus@test.com'],
                    ['id' => 13371337, 'company' => 'Test store 2', 'email' => 'katja@test.com'],
                ]);
        });

    $action->execute();
}
```

What ever I'm trying it still makes live calls, i.e my Mock is not being used in my test. I figure this has something to do with that my classes might not come from the container. I have tried to bind both the `ApiClient` and the `Action` in the container with the same results.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried to do this with my classes, but it doesn't seem to work this way. Or I don't know how to do it either, I solved it by making a Http fake of the url. In your case you would have to make a Http Fake of the url that your library points to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be really simple to solve, you have to invert the first 2 lines of code, so:

```
this->mock(ApiClient::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('ambassadors')->once()
            ->andReturn([
                ['id' => 1337, 'company' => 'Test store 1', 'email' => 'marcus@test.com'],
                ['id' => 13371337, 'company' => 'Test store 2', 'email' => 'katja@test.com'],
            ]);
    });
$action = app(Action::class);
```

This is because, you are first telling the Container that you are mocking `ApiClient` and then instancing `Action`, if you do it the other way around, you have already instanced `Action` hence also `ApiClient`.

Comment: I still get the same issue. Do I need to bind the `ApiClient` class to the container in order for it to be able to swap it? I have tried to bind it but it still wont work.

Comment: Strange, as `$this->mock` already binds the instance